# Creating UpdatePanel dynamically for a custom control is causing a full post back

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel

I've been jammed on this for a day now. I need to create a custom control, and for a proof of concept, I am trying to create the UpdatePanel and add a button into it. **It always causes a full page post back**.

Code (custom control):

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports AjaxControlToolkit

<Designer(GetType(HMXICDSearchToolDesigner))> _
Public Class HMXICDSearchTool
Inherits HMXISBaseCompositeControl
Implements INamingContainer

Private Const DEFAULT_WIDTH As Integer = 650
Private Const DEFAULT_HEIGHT As Integer = 450

Private _pnlUpdate As UpdatePanel = Nothing
Private _btnTest As Button = Nothing
Private _lbl As Label = Nothing

Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
    MyBase.CreateChildControls()

    _pnlUpdate = New UpdatePanel()
    With _pnlUpdate
        .ID = "pnlUpdate"
        .ChildrenAsTriggers = False
        .UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
    End With

    _btnTest = New Button()
    With _btnTest
        .ID = "btnTest"
        .Text = "Test Button"
        .CausesValidation = False
        AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Btn_Click
    End With

    _lbl = New Label()
    With _lbl
        .ID = "lbl"
        .Text = "Hello!"
    End With

    _pnlUpdate.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_btnTest)
    _pnlUpdate.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_lbl)

    Dim aTrigger As AsyncPostBackTrigger = New AsyncPostBackTrigger()
    With aTrigger
        .ControlID = "btnTest"
        .EventName = "Click"
    End With

    Me._pnlUpdate.Triggers.Add(aTrigger)

    Me.Controls.Add(_pnlUpdate)

    Me.Style.Add("background-color", "red")
    Me.Height = 500
    Me.Width = 500
End Sub

Protected Sub Btn_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not Me.Page.IsPostBack Then
        Me._lbl.Text = "Async postback."
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I have tried toggling ChildrenAsTriggers, putting this code in Me.Load, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was performing a partial postback the whole time.**

I made the mistake of testing to see if it was a partial postback like so:

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
   'something here
End
```

When I should have been checking this

```
Me.ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostback
```

This: `Page.IsPostBack` will be **true** even if it is performing a partial postback.